# constraint check values with regular expression

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints, regular-expression

In a table with a field `code`, I want to authorize the user to choose **one** value among a list.
Here is a sample of the values of the list :

```
A|AG|AL|AS|B|C|D|DA
```

I added a constraint on `code` like this :

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT verif_code CHECK (code::text ~ '(A|AG|AL|AS|B|C|D|DA)')
```

Despite of this, I can add an extra value **after** a first one picked up in the list.

```
ALY accepted -> :(
Y   rejected -> :)
```

How to avoid the possibility of adding a value in the second position that is not in the list?

(I could use a `IN` operator but at the end, the authorized values for `code` will be a combinaison of three sets of lists.)

Answer (score 1):

The value matches the condition because it contains `A`.

Regular expressions are not only complicated to understand, they are also often expensive to process (there is a connection between these two). So if you can do without them, do it.

In this case, the check constraint should be

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT verif_code CHECK (code IN ('A', 'AG', 'AL', 'AS', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'DA'));
```

Comment: "Each part will be taken from a list": then you cannot use that in a check constraint, because you need to know that list when you create the constraint. That cannot be a list that changes based on what is in the database or something else that is not immutable. Perhaps you can ask another question that describes your actual problem.

Comment: @Leehan: it sounds as if that "list" should be a separate table. Then use a foreign key reference from `mytable` to that "list table"

Comment: Or maybe it could be split using generated columns?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) suggested:

> If I understand correctly, it could probably be solved with a complex regex, e.g. `CHECK (code SIMILAR TO '(A|AG|AL|AS|B|C|D|DA)(1|2|3|4)(X|Y|Z)')` for a code that consists of 3 parts, the first as described in the question, the second part a digit from 1 to 4 and the 3rd part of a character, either X, Y or Z.

This expression works as expected:

```
code SIMILAR TO ('(A|AG|AL|AS|B|C|D|DA|DL|DS|G|GA)(d|h|l|m)?(_lab|_g|_h|_o)?')
```

One element of first list followed or not by one element of second list followed or not by one element of third list.

ex: Ad ; AG_g ; DSh_lab.